# How to check if file exist or not with first 8 digits of filename in ETL?

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon

I want to check the file in server. The file name having 14 digits like(**20160906005212.csv**).

I know the filename of first 8 digits its yesterdays date(**20160906**). But next 6 digit is time, it will differ. Based on date(**20160906xxxxxx.csv**) I want to check the file exist with the date.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Currently, I rename it and checking like the following.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a transformation, use a 'Get file names' step. Example:

[image]

You can use a 'Detect empty stream' step to handle the case when there are no files.